# Boilerplate code in the definition of a monad

Tags: haskell, monads, functor, applicative

Since the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal), Monads are a subclass of Applicative which in turn is a subclass of Functor. Mathematically speaking, this seems to be a sensible choice and I do not have any problems with that.

However, what is irritating me is that one is required to write down the Functor and Applicative instances even if the corresponding laws for `fmap` and `pure` and `<*>` are fixed by the monad laws anyways. Indeed, in the above linked proposal, they write themselves: "You can simply derive these instances from the Monad by adding the following code":

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative(..))
import Control.Monad       (liftM, ap)

instance Functor m where
    fmap = liftM

instance Applicative m where
    pure  = {- move the definition of `return` from the `Monad` instance here -}
    (<*>) = ap
```

and in most tutorials, you will simply see the equality `pure=return` and people then go on to define `return` in the Monad instance as before. Therefore, effectively, 10 lines of boilerplate code were added for everyone who simply wants to define a Monad instance.

In mathematics, one usually also does not operate in this way. For example, when defining the composition laws for a certain ring, the reader is usually not explicitly reminded again that rings are special instances of abelian groups under addition which in turn are special instances of groups. This is clear by definition anyways.

Thus my question is: Even though it is fine that Monads are a subclass of Applicative which in turn is a subclass of Functor, couldn't this just "happen in the background" in the sense that the compiler inserts the boilerplate code instead of the programmer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice from the documentation is for legacy types that used to have a `Monad` instance defined but no `Applicative` one. Then defining those instances *in terms of* the existing `Monad` one is a quick and reliable fix to get the package to compile again.

However, this is not how it should go for new code, since `Monad` is actually the more advanced class. The recommended way is to

1. *Derive* the `Functor` instance. There is always only one possible way this can be done, and the compiler can do it for you.

   ```
   {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
   data YourMonadType a = ...
     deriving (Functor)
   ```
2. Define `Applicative`. This is not quite automatic, and sometimes `<*>` can be a bit counterintuitive, but you'll get the hang of it and a direct implementation can actually be more efficient than `(<*>) = ap`.

   ```
   instance Applicative YourMonadType where
     pure = {- direct definition here -}
     q <*> r = {- direct definition here -}
   ```
3. Define `Monad`. This won't require `return` at all (because it's default `= pure`), just `>>=`.

   ```
   instance Monad YourMonadType where
     q >>= f = {- direct definition here -}
   ```

   Side note: arguably the method of `Monad` should actually be [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) instead of `>>=`. Whilst `return` and `>>=` give rise to all the `Functor` and `Applicative` methods, `join` is an “orthogonal feature” to them.

---

In modern GHC it is also possible to obtain a derive-instance for `Applicative` by using the `via` strategy on the [`WrappedMonad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:WrappedMonad) newtype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingVia, DeriveFunctor #-}

import Control.Applicative

data YourMonadType a = YourMonadType a a
  deriving stock (Functor, Show)
  deriving Applicative via (WrappedMonad YourMonadType)

instance Monad YourMonadType where
  return x = YourMonadType x x
  YourMonadType x y >>= f = YourMonadType fx fy
   where YourMonadType fx _ = f x
         YourMonadType _ fy = f y
```

```
ghci> YourMonadType (+1) (*2) <*> YourMonadType 10 20
YourMonadType 11 40
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a good remark that Functor can be derived, that's cool. However, still the overall code will be more than before where one was able to simply go with the Monad instance (because `<*>` is actually given by `>>=` but one has to rewrite it (perhaps for many occasions the gain in performance wouldn't be needed). Couldn't one at least allow both options: 1) to do it as you point out, 2) to let the compiler handle the case when the programmer only defines the Monad instance?

Comment: Yes, it is a bit more code. But you shouldn't be writing `Monad` instances very often anyway, so it's pretty much a non-issue. For more complicated class hierarchies this _can_ become a significant burden though. It would be nice if Haskell had some feature that allowed “skipping” superclass instances, but there's no such thing.

Comment: "It would be nice if Haskell had some feature that allowed “skipping” superclass instances" - Yes, that would be cool. Indeed, this issue would come up in all cases where such a hierarchy was defined. I upvoted your answer. If you add that such a superclass skipping feature would be nice, I'd accept it.

Comment: Well, you could always define an `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` catch-all instance, but overlapping instances are a bit of a dark art that can easily lead to unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: How would you implement this? Would adding `{-# OVERLAPPABLE #-}` to the beginning of the file allow for defining the Monad instance without the Applicative instance? But I see that one has to be careful not to overwrite something unintentionally.

Comment: There's no sensible way to exploit overlapp*** pragmas for the monad hierarchy, but for a custom `class C a` / `class C a => D a` hierarchy you could define `instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} D a => C a where { {-fallback definitions -} }`. But there are several problems with this.

Comment: @leftaroundabout "It would be nice if Haskell had some feature that allowed 'skipping' superclass instances" -- Haskell doesn't have one, but GHC does. We could have a DefaultSignatures definition of `pure = return`. Could this loop if you implemented neither `pure` nor `return`? Sure, but then... so what?

Comment: @DanielWagner using `DefaultSignatures` this way doesn't lead to much good in my experience, but I just remembered that `DerivingVia` is a pretty good alternative.

Comment: Using `WrappedMonad` is not correct, `pure` diverges if you run it! This is because of the "`Monad` of no `return`" propsal. See issues [*#13876*](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/13876) and [*#14200*](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/14200).

Comment: @Iceland_jack please edit with whatever you think appropriate.